# How to remove a specific value from an array stored in a ruby hash

Tags: ruby, arrays, hashset

I am getting this in my error list :

```
@error_messages = {
                   :password=>["can't be blank", "Password is required."], 
                   :"addresses.firstname"=>["can't be blank","Firstname is required."],
                   :"addresses.city"=>["can't be blank", "city is required."]
                  }
```

Here I want to remove the value "can't be blank" value from this hash so that I will get the validation error messages which was included by me.

is it possible to remove "can't be blank" value from above hash list and I will get this in result :

```
       @error_messages = {
                          :password=>["Password is required."],
                          :"addresses.firstname"=>["Firstname is required."],
                          :"addresses.city"=>["city is required."]
                         }
```

How to remove a specific value from a hash list(want to remove  a specific value not a complete key,value pair).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, possible.

```
@error_messages = {
                   :password=>["can't be blank", "Password is required."], 
                   :"addresses.firstname"=>["can't be blank","Firstname is required."],
                   :"addresses.city"=>["can't be blank", "city is required."]
                  }

@error_messages.each do |_,v|
   v.delete( "can't be blank" )
end

@error_messages
# => {:password=>["Password is required."],
#     :"addresses.firstname"=>["Firstname is required."],
#     :"addresses.city"=>["city is required."]}
```